# Recuperar itens de ListView

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando criar um aplicativo de vendas, onde no pedido eu seleciono o produto a ser vendido e clico em um botão adicionar, e o produto selecionado é jogado para dentro de uma listview, quando o vendedor terminou de selecionar todos os produtos e adicionar na listview ele clica no botão concluir, fazendo todos os inserts na tabela, mas estou com problemas para recuperar os itens dentro da tabela para fazer os inserts.

Para colocar os itens dentro da listview eu faço desta forma:

Classe **Produtos**:

```
package br.com.realsysten.venda;

public class Produtos {

  private String  id;
  private String descricao;
  private String quantidade;
  private String  preco;

  public Produtos(){

  }

  public Produtos(String id, String descricao, String quantidade, String preco){
    this.id = id;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
    this.preco = preco;
  }

  public String getId(){
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getPreco() {
    return preco;
  }

  public void setPreco(String preco) {
    this.preco = preco;
  }

  public String getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
  }

  public void setQuantidade(String quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
  }

  public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
  }

  public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
  }
}
```

Classe **ProdutosAdapter**:

```
public class ProdutosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater prodInf;
  private ArrayList<Produtos> produtos;

  public ProdutosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Produtos> produtos){
    this.produtos = produtos;

    prodInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return produtos.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return produtos.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Produtos produto = produtos.get(position);
    view = prodInf.inflate(R.layout.pedido_produto_modelo, null);

    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpId)).setText(produto.getId());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpDescricao)).setText(produto.getDescricao());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpqtd)).setText(produto.getQuantidade());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpPreco)).setText(produto.getPreco());

    return view;
  }
}
```

Classe **PedidoProdutos**:

```
public class PedidoProdutoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

  String quant;
  String stotal;
  String novoId;
  String novaDescricao;
  String novaQtd;
  String novoPreco;
  double dpreco;
  int iqtd;
  double dtotal;
  ProdutosAdapter produtosAdapter;
  ArrayList<Produtos> produtos;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pedido_produto);

    EditText data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtData);
    final String currentDataTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    data.setText(currentDataTimeString);
    produtos = new ArrayList<Produtos>();

    //SPINNER CLIENTE

    Spinner spCliente = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCliente);
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("vendas.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cursorCliente = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, PAR_RAZAO_NOME FROM PARCERIA ORDER " +
            "BY PAR_RAZAO_NOME ASC", null);

    String[] fromCliente = {"_id", "PAR_RAZAO_NOME"};
    int[] toCliente = {R.id.txcId, R.id.txcNome};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adCliente = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_cliente,
            cursorCliente, fromCliente, toCliente, 0);

    spCliente.setAdapter(adCliente);

    // SPINNER PAGAMENTO

    Spinner spPagamento = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPagamento);
    Cursor cursorPag = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, CPAG_DESCRICAO FROM CONDICAO_PAGTO ORDER" +
            " BY CPAG_DESCRICAO ASC", null);

    String[] fromPag = {"_id", "CPAG_DESCRICAO"};
    int[] toPag = {R.id.txpId, R.id.txpDescricao};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adPag = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_pagamentos,
            cursorPag, fromPag, toPag, 0);
    spPagamento.setAdapter(adPag);

    // SPINNER CARTEIRA

    Spinner spCarteira = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCarteira);
    Cursor cursorCar = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, CAR_NOME FROM CARTEIRA ORDER BY CAR_NOME ASC",
            null);

    String[] fromCar = {"_id", "CAR_NOME"};
    int[] toCar = {R.id.txcaId, R.id.txcaNome};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adCar = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_carteira,
            cursorCar, fromCar, toCar, 0);
    spCarteira.setAdapter(adCar);

    // SPINNER PRODUTOS

    Spinner spProdutos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spProduto);
    Cursor cursorPro = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, PRO_DESCRICAO, PRO_PUNIT_VENDA FROM PRODUTOS " +
            "ORDER BY PRO_DESCRICAO ASC",null);

    String[] fromPro = {"_id", "PRO_DESCRICAO", "PRO_PUNIT_VENDA"};
    int[] toPro = {R.id.txproId, R.id.txproDescricao, R.id.txproPreco};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adPro = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_produtos,
            cursorPro, fromPro, toPro, 0);
    spProdutos.setAdapter(adPro);
    db.close();

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ListView lstpro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);
            EditText eqtd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtQuantidade);
            Spinner spProd = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spProduto);
            SQLiteCursor dados = (SQLiteCursor) spProd.getAdapter().getItem(spProd.getSelectedItemPosition());

            final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
            final Cursor cursor = crud.carregaDadosByIdProd(dados.getInt(0));

            quant = String.valueOf(eqtd.getText());
            dpreco = dados.getDouble(2);

            iqtd = Integer.parseInt(quant);
            dtotal = dpreco * iqtd;

            stotal = String.valueOf(dtotal);

            novoId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getProId()));
            novaDescricao = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getProDescricao()));
            novoPreco = stotal;
            novaQtd = quant;

            //ADAPTER PERSONALIZADO:

            Produtos item = new Produtos(novoId, novaDescricao, novaQtd, novoPreco);

            produtos.add(item);

            produtosAdapter = new ProdutosAdapter(getBaseContext(), produtos);

            lstpro.setAdapter(produtosAdapter);
            setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(lstpro);
        }
    });

    Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lstprod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);

            int linhas = lstprod.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){

                final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
                crud.op = 2;


            }




        }
    });
  }

  public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView){

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if(listAdapter != null){

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;

        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++){

            float px = 300 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);
        int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

esse trecho:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lstprod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);

            int linhas = lstprod.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){
                final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
                crud.op = 2;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

é onde estou tentando fazer o insert dos itens dentro da listview.

Comment: Poste o código que implementou.

Comment: editei o post com mais informações

Comment: ninguem sabe ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia, 
Pelo que interpretei no seu código você tem uma variável global chamada `Produtos` e você vai adicionando cada produto selecionado nessa lista. Essa lista é passada para `Listview` cada vez que um Item é adicionado.

Nesse caso não vejo necessidade de você recuperar os item da `Listview` uma  vez que na sua lista `Produtos` estão todos os itens selecionados.

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (Produto produto: Produtos){
           insert(produto) // seu código para fazer o insert
        }
    }
});
```

}

Agora se mesmo assim você deseja pegar o item da ListView basta fazer assim:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lstprod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);

            int linhas = lstprod.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){
                Produto produto = (Produto) lstprod.getItemAtPosition(i)
                final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
                crud.op = 2;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Espero ajudar. Flw